# Property 'msHidden' does not exist on type 'Document'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, interface

I am getting this error while using tab visibility . In which 'msHidden' and 'webkitHidden' does not exist on type 'Document'

```
const TabVisibilityComponent = () => {
let hidden = null;
let visibilityChange = '';
const [action, setAction] = useState('show');
if (typeof document.hidden !== 'undefined') {
  hidden = 'hidden';
  visibilityChange = 'visibilitychange';
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== 'undefined') {
  hidden = 'msHidden';
  visibilityChange = 'msvisibilitychange';
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== 'undefined') {
  hidden = 'webkitHidden';
  visibilityChange = 'webkitvisibilitychange';
}

const handleVisibilityChange = () => {
  if (document.hidden) {
    setAction('hide');
  } else {
    setAction('show');
  }
};


useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange, false);
  window.addEventListener(
    'focus',
    function() {
      setAction('show');
    },
    false,
  );
  window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    setAction('hide');
  }, false);
}, [visibilityChange]);
return <p></p>;
};

export default TabVisibilityComponent;
```

I have tried adding **'readonly msHidden: boolean'** in the Document interface in **'lib.dom.d.ts'** file, because hidden works fine and it is declared as readonly boolean in that file so tried the same for msHidden and webkitHidden but it is not working. I have seen this code used by many but don't know what's the mistake with mine. Would be much happy if anyone got a solution for this !

Answer (score 3):

The code comes straight from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) so you're right that the code itself is fine.  The issues are:

---

1. The `lib.dom` definitions do include browser-specific properties.

One of the ways to get around this is to pass the document as an argument to a function which defines those properties as optional.

```
const hiddenPropName = (document: Document & {msHidden?: boolean; webkitHidden?: boolean}) => {
  if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined" ) {
    return "hidden";
  } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
    return "msHidden";
  } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
    return "webkitHidden";
  }
  // not sure how to handle when none exist
}
```

But as far as Typescript is concerned, `document.hidden` always exists.

It looks like there is hardly any difference between the numbers for prefixed and un-prefixed support on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=document.hidden).  So You could just ditch the `msHidden` and `webkitHidden`.

---

2. You are ignoring the `hidden` and `visibilityChange` variables that you set.

The first section of the code in the example is just setting the variables `hidden` and `visibilityChange` to the names of the properties so that they can access the correct properties later on.  The example uses `document[hidden]` where `hidden` is a variable, but you used `document.hidden` which always gets the property "hidden" and never "msHidden" or "webkitHidden".

They are also using a variable for the event in the `document.addEventListener`.

If you want to support the prefixes then you need to use variable property and event names.  If not, just delete that whole first code block.

---

3. You are not adapting the code properly to React.

You want to make sure that your `useEffect` hook has the correct dependencies and you ideally should use a cleanup function in your `useEffect` to remove the event listeners on unmount.

The hardest part here is making sure that you aren't creating any stale closures that will use outdated values of `document` when evaluating.  I'm actually not sure without playing with it if this is correct:

```
const TabVisibilityComponent = () => {
  const [action, setAction] = useState("show");

  useEffect(() => {
    const hide = () => setAction("hide");

    const show = () => setAction("show");

    const handleVisibilityChange = () => {
      document.hidden ? hide() : show();
    };

    document.addEventListener(
      "visibilitychange",
      handleVisibilityChange,
      false
    );
    window.addEventListener("focus", show, false);
    window.addEventListener("blur", hide, false);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);
      window.removeEventListener("focus", show);
      window.removeEventListener("blur", hide);
    };
  }, [setAction]);

  return <p></p>;
};
```